# How to schedule SSIS import when the data source is daily excel sheet in email?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, schedule

Hi I have a specific question regarding scheduling SSIS import:

I have a data source which will send me scheduled excel sheet to my email inbox on daily basis. The expectation is to find a solution which will take this daily excel sheet email into SSIS and schedule importing into SQL on its own.

Is it possible at all? If anyone could provide some useful links or where shall I start to look into, it will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: what mail client are you currently using

Comment: If you can find some links that tell you how to do it in .NET, then you can do it with a script task.

Answer (score 0):

Sense there was no answer to the mail client yet I am just going to throw this out there.

This will work on Gmail and is configured for such.

First thing first you have to make sure that you enable POP (this will allow the process to read your inbox). It is suggested that you select "enable pop from now on" as it will only allow the viewing of items from that point forward.

Once you have done that you need to get the Nuget package for OpenPOP.net

now the fun part. Please keep in mind this is not proper coding practice and you are responsible for the addition of necessary security precautions and error handling. This is purely a proof of concept.

```
    using OpenPop.Pop3;
    using OpenPop.Mime;
    using OpenPop.Mime.Header;

            // create the client to be used 
            Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client();

            // connect to the client via host server port and use ssl bool
            client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);

            // log into the specific account to read
            client.Authenticate("username", "password");

            // generate count of emails in the inbox
            int msgcount = client.GetMessageCount();

    //loop thru available message numbers via message count 
    //incremented at the end of the while loop
    while (msgcount > 0)
            {
                // gets the message header info to, from and subject ect.
                MessageHeader header = client.GetMessageHeaders(msgcount);

                //read the subject line
                string subject = header.Subject;

                //compare subject to identify the correct email 
                if (subject.ToLower() == "subject to match")
                {
                    // gets message info based on message number from msgcount
                    var message = client.GetMessage(msgcount);

                    // creates list of the attachments available in the message
                    List<MessagePart> attachments = message.FindAllAttachments();

                    //loops thru attachments 
                    foreach (var file in attachments)
                    {
                        //assigns filename as string for stream
                        string filename = file.FileName;

                       //create a stream to download the file
                        var stream = new FileStream(@"destination path" + filename,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite);

                        // downloads file
                        file.Save(stream);

                        // closes stream to protect system and hung files
                        stream.Close();
                    }
                    // optional and must be configured to be allowed in your 
                    // email client.
                    client.DeleteMessage(msgcount);
                }
                 // increment message number 
                 msgcount--;
            }
            // this is extremely important if deleting or manipulating files in inbox
            //the above deletemessage command only marked the message to be deleted.
            // you must commit the change to have it take effect.
            // this command commits the changes you have made. 
            // this also closes your client connection so that no connections are left open. 
            client.Dispose();
```

This can be added to a script task in your import and you can then download the excel file and import it as you normally would if you would have manually pulled the file and placed it on a hard disk or network drive.